# I am unable to import the safe math library in my 0.6.12 version of my compiler

Tags: solidity, remix, error, openzeppelin-contracts, version-pragma

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.6.12;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Comment: its showing me that the error as @openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol not found

Comment: Why are you still using Solidity v0.6?

Comment: Nothing it's just to match a project requirement so just doing some minor changes to kept the same only .

Answer (score 0):

The path for the safeMath is Changed in Openzepplin.

You need to import it from..

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
```